# How to load numbers from a .txt file to C

Tags: c, text, numbers, load, file-handling

I need to load numbers from a text file and then manipulate those numbers for further jobs in my code.
"m(0,1,2,5,7,10,15)"  --> this is what is inside my text file

Can somebody help me? It will be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try yourself: do it by steps:
1. first locate the file and open it for reading
2. read the data from file (print it to see that its actually read)
3. break the data - i will leave it up to you to find a way but i am sure that a google search for something like parsing a string will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a command line example you could modify to suit your needs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *sptr;
    if (argc < 2) return 1;
    sptr = strtok(argv[1], "m(,)");
    while (sptr)
        {
        printf ("%d,", atoi(sptr));
        sptr = strtok(NULL, "m(,)");
        }
    return 0;
}
```